# R XGBoost - xgb.save or xgb.load loss of data

Tags: r, xgboost

After training an XGBoost model in R, I am presented with a model object called `xgb` which is a `list of 7`.

When I save the model using `xgb.save` and then reload using `xgb.load`, I am presented with what seems to be a 'smaller' model object which is a `list of 2`.

Obviously I can't share the code as you would need the training data which is massive, so all I can really show is a picture of the variable editor.

Below is model object `xgb` which is the original model after training, vs. the model object `test1` which is the same model but saved and reloaded:

[image]

Why does this happen and am I losing valuable information upon saving/loading my models?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe late, but I was having the same problem and found a solution.

Saving the xgb-model as "rds" doesn't loose any information and the reloaded model xgb_ does generate the same forecast values as the original xgb when I tested it. Hope that helps!

```
saveRDS(xgb, "model.rds")
xgb_ <- readRDS("model.rds")
all.equal(xgb, xgb_)
```

Comment: This is wrong. `saveRDS` will also save the handle which will be invalid when loaded in an other R session (or after restarting R). See here: https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/160

Answer (score 0):

You are loosing information due to rounding errors after save/load. See [this](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/160) issue. I believe it is currently a bug.

As to why the loaded model is a smaller list, see [here](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/5209). So again, you are loosing information such as the callbacks and parameters. But these are not essential for prediction and not portable to e.g. python.